# jQuery Mobile swipe event not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, gesture

Currently I'm trying to develop own carousel with gesture support. Support is pretty simple - when user swipe left or right it triggers corresponding function. However, event is not triggered during swipe left and right.
My pen is there https://codepen.io/CrUsH20/pen/yvQxKE
I've imported jQuery and jQuery Mobile afterwards. But I don't get any result. My functions are near bottom and followed by comment.
Functions look so

```
$($this).on('swipeleft', function(event) {
    scrollToNext();
});
$($this).on('swiperight', function(event) {
    scrollToPrevious();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
jQuery Mobile 1.5 requires jQuery 2.1 meanwhile I was using 3.xx